# Find the highest power of 1980 such that

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factorial

I am asked to find the highest power of $1980$ that divides the integer $$N=\frac{(1980n)!}{(n!)^{1980}}$$ I have no idea where to start, since the factorials don't seem able to be simplified. Can you please give me a hint or a boost that could help?

Comment: A factor can be "simplified" by $(1980n)! = \prod_{k=1}^{1980} k *\prod_{k=1980}^{2*1980} k *....*\prod_{k=(n-1)1980+1}^{1980n} k= \prod_{j=0}^{n-1}(\prod_{k=1980j+1}^{1980(j+1)}k)$ or $(1980n)!=\prod_{i=0}^{1979}(\prod_{h=in+1}^{n(i+1)}i)$.  And note that $1980!$ will divide each  $\prod_{k=1980j+1}^{1980(j+1)}k$ and $n!$ will divide each $\prod_{h=in+1}^{n(i+1)}i$.

Answer (score 0):

[Legendre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula) for the exponent of a prime in a factorial may be useful, as well as the factorization $1980 = 2^2 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 5 \cdot 11$.

But I don't think there's a very simple formula for the answer.  For $n$ from $1$ to $20$ I get
$$197, 394, 493, 790, 493, 988, 1384, 986, 493, 988, 197, 394, 592, 790, 989, 986, 1385, 988, 1482, 1976$$